# EF 4.3 fluent mapping Intermediate table TPT

Tags: entity-framework, fluent, entity-framework-4.3

I have the following legacy table structure (simplified for this post)
[image]

The following is my feeble attempt at configuring the Entity:

```
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity> {
public EntityConfiguration() {
  ToTable("Entity");
  HasKey(x => x.Id);
  Property(x => x.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

  HasMany(x => x.TypeOneUpdateBlacklist)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => {
      x.ToTable("UpdateBlacklist");
      x.MapLeftKey("EntityId");
      x.MapRightKey("UpdateId");
    });

  HasMany(x => x.TypeTwoUpdateBlacklist)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => {
      x.ToTable("UpdateBlacklist");
      x.MapLeftKey("EntityId");
      x.MapRightKey("UpdateId");
    });
}
```

The configuration renders this error:

**The EntitySet 'EntityBlacklistUpdate' with schema 'dbo' and table 'UpdateBlacklist' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table.**

Is there away to configure this? Thanks in advance

Comment: It would appear this is not possible. The only workable solution I can come up with is two different tables TypeOneUpdateBlacklist and TypeTwoUpdateBlacklist.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the many-to-many mapping with the base type `Update`:

```
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity> {
    public EntityConfiguration() {
    ToTable("Entity");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    HasMany(x => x.Updates)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x => {
            x.ToTable("UpdateBlacklist");
            x.MapLeftKey("EntityId");
            x.MapRightKey("UpdateId");
    });
}
```

However, it would require that your class `Entity` does only have a navigation collection `Updates` of the base type instead of two navigation collections for the two derived types. And it is only possible if the database schema really represents an inheritance model, i.e. a given `Update` row can *either* have a related `TypeOneUpdate` *or* a `TypeTwoUpdate` row, both never *both*. If it can have both, you cannot map this with TPT but you would have to create one-to-one relationships.